# Drupal cms Mixed (insecure) display content on drupal

Tags: https

anyone here who has knowledge in drupal. I've set up .htaccess file for https redirection but now I have problems with images on my website. On almost all images there is http link not https .
Is there any general settings?

Web pages are: https://www.gostol-tst.eu/ and https://www.irsmartwheel.eu/ they both run on a same server.

Thanks for answers, Ivan

Comment: For the quick solution just clear the drupal cache and try run on https and check.

Comment: Tnx, somehow works ;-)